# Задать свойства css для элемента, если предыдущий элемент считается :last-child

Tags: css

Есть пример кода. В нем мы видим, что у двух `div` есть класс `new-alert-item`. Как прописать свойства `css` для одного `div class="nf-line"`, который стоит после последнего `div new-alert-item`? Количество `new-alert-item` не статично, их число постоянно меняется.

```css
.alerts .new-alert-item:last-child ~ .nf-line{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="alerts">
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">1</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">2</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">3</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">4</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, подойдёт что-то такое:

```css
.alerts {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.alert-item-wrapp {
  order: 1;
}

.new-alert-item {
  order: -1;
}

.alerts::after {
  content: "";
  height: 1em;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="alerts">
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">1</div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">2</div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">3</div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но количество `new-alert-item` не статично, их число постоянно меняется.

Comment: @АннаМатвеева, но мой ответ никак не зависит от их количества...

Answer (score 4):

"Задать свойства css для элемента, если предыдущий элемент считается :last-child" - полный бред. Если элемент ":last-child", он по определению не может быть "предыдущим", он последний (у данного родителя).

`nth-of-type()` и `last-of-type` не сработают, т.к. у вас всё `<div>`'ы. Но если бы вы могли элементы с классом `new-alert-item` сделать какими-то другими, то получилось бы.

Конкретно в вашей ситуации, если заранее неизвестно количество элементов с классом `new-alert-item`, то без JS не обойтись. Ну а если их именно два, то можно так:

```css
.alerts .new-alert-item~.new-alert-item+.nf-line {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="alerts">
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">1</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">2</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">3</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">4</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. Может подскажете как реализовать при помощи JS?

Answer (score 1):

После того, как появится поддержка селектора [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has), вероятно, заработает такое (если у кого есть сафари 15.4+, прокомментируйте пожалуйста):

```css
.new-alert-item + .nf-line:not(:has(~ .new-alert-item)) {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="alerts">
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">1</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">2</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">3</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">4</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ответ у вас конечно супер универсальный...

Comment: @ΝNL993, ну не ставить же мне таймер "зайти через полгода и написать ответ с селектором :has"))) Вообще, вроде можно экспериментальными флагами и в других браузерах включить.

Answer (score 1):

Запись `.elem:nth-child(2)` вернёт не второй элемент из всех `.elem`, а именно второй из всех элементов которые есть в том же родителе, в котором находится `.`.
Т.е. запись `.parent .elem:nth-child(2)` будет эквивалентен `.parent *:nth-child(2)`.

Да, было бы круто если бы было так же как `document.getElementsByClassName('.elem')[1]`, но увы.
Вашу логику проще реализовать на JS.

```js
let selector = document.querySelectorAll('.new-alert-item');
let selectorLast = selector[selector.length - 1]
let selectorNext = selectorLast.nextElementSibling; // берём следующий элемент у последнего `.new-alert-item`


if(selectorNext.classList.contains('nf-line')) // если след. элемент `.nf-line`
  selectorNext.style.border = '1px solid #000'; // то выдаём ему бордер
else
  selectorLast.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="nf-line" style="border: 1px solid #000"></div>'); // Если нет, то создаём такой элемент.
```

```html
<div class="alerts">
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">1</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">2</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">3</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">4</div>
  <div class="nf-line"></div>
</div>
```

Так же можно вообще убрать `.nf-line`, JS его создаст.

```js
let selector = document.querySelectorAll('.new-alert-item');
let selectorLast = selector[selector.length - 1]
let selectorNext = selectorLast.nextElementSibling; // берём следующий элемент у последнего `.new-alert-item`


if(selectorNext.classList.contains('nf-line')) // если след. элемент `.nf-line`
  selectorNext.style.border = '1px solid #000'; // то выдаём ему бордер
else
  selectorLast.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="nf-line" style="border: 1px solid #000"></div>'); // Если нет, то создаём такой элемент.
```

```html
<div class="alerts">
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">1</div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp new-alert-item">2</div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">3</div>
  <div class="alert-item-wrapp">4</div>
</div>
```